# How do I access a Parse objects properties?

Tags: javascript, object, parse-platform

I'm running the following in my Parse background job:

```
  var pushIncrement = Parse.Object.extend("pushIncrement");
  var pushIncrementQuery = new Parse.Query(pushIncrement);
  pushIncrementQuery.equalTo('objectId', 'hKj2Eazz6h');

  pushIncrementQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
       console.log('Here are the results:' + results);
       status.success("Completed successfully.");
    },

    error: function(error) {
       console.log('shit');
       status.error('shitty shit');
    }
  });
```

`results` is a Parse object. If for instance, I was querying all `matchCenterItem` objects, `results` would be returned with a format like this:

```
<matchCenterItem: 0x7f84e2c1a4b0, objectId: Je1VxP7dPw, localId: (null)> {
    categoryId = 9355;
    itemCondition = Used;
    itemLocation = US;
    maxPrice = 350;
    minPrice = 250;
    parent = "<PFUser: 0x7f84e2c20c10, objectId: kfEHfG4FUD>";
    searchTerm = "iphone 5 unlocked";
}
```

Now if I wanted to access for example, the `categoryId` property of `results` and console log it, how would I do that? I tried something like the following in the success function, but it didn't work as I expected:

`console.log('Here's the categoryId:' + results.categoryId);`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, can do it like this:

```
var pushIncrement = Parse.Object.extend("pushIncrement");
  var pushIncrementQuery = new Parse.Query(pushIncrement);
  pushIncrementQuery.equalTo('objectId', 'hKj2Eazz6h');

  pushIncrementQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        var dayNumber = results[i].get("Number");
      }
       console.log('dem results be:' + dayNumber);
       status.success("Push Notifications completed successfully.");

    },

    error: function(error) {
       console.log('shit');
       status.error('shitty shit');
    }
  });
```

Comment: You got it, but I would also add that if you were trying to access the `objectId` of the `parent` object, you would write `results[i].get("parent").id` and if you wanted to access the whole `parent` object in your results you would add `pushIncrementQuery.include("parent")` to your query and would access through `results[i].get("parent").get("somePropertyOfParent")`

Comment: @dstefanis Ah makes sense. Now immediately after this, I attempt to edit the `Number` value of the object like so: `for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        var dayNumber = results[i].get("Number");
      }

      //Figure out whether its day 1, 2, or 3, and increment. Send lowPush if day 3.
      if (dayNumber = 1){
        //change it to 2
        console.log('dayNumber is 1');

        results.set('Number', '2');
        results.save();
      }`

But it gives me an error saying ` Result: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'set'`.

Comment: spotted two errors in the above code. First is unrelated, but your `if` statement should be `if (dayNumber == 1)` - you're missing an equals sign which will cause a different problem for you down the road. The second issue is that you are trying to set the `Number` property of `results` instead of `results[i]`. Hope that helps